# Reference External Project in Spring Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to reference a project in my main project.  I am a .NET developer so I am having a hard time knowing the correct way to reference it.  I have a data project and a data project in a MAVEN multiple project setup.  In the screenshot you can see I am trying to reference a DAO object from my data project in the security.xml file in my Spring MVC web project.  When I run the project it says it can not find the correct class.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I fixed this by adding a Maven dependency of my project, which created a JAR for Tomcat, and fixed the issue.  I didn't know you could search the Maven Local Repository to use your own projects.